# Efficiently send dataframe in Spark to other application

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to send the dataframe in Spark context to my client application. Currently, I just convert the dataframe to a list in memory and send the list via ZMQ to the client. But calling Dataframe.collectAsList() takes much time. Is there any way to improve the speed for this process? Or should I try other way to pass data from Spark to other app? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `foreachPartition` method. Like i.e:

```
df.foreachPartition(iterator => {
  val connection = createConnection(...)
  iterator.foreach(row => connection.send(row))
  connection.close()
}
```

In this case Spark will create N parallel connections, where N - is the number of allocated executors. The data will be sent from executors directly and there will be no need to collect the entire dataset to driver. But be careful, you must be sure that your application can handle the possible load.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. I think this is the way to solve my problem. Could you also offer a Java example? I tried to code the Java version but get stuck in the returned BoxedUnit. I went through this tutorial but could not get the lambda version working in Java 8 https://pythagoreanscript.wordpress.com/2015/05/28/iterate-through-a-spark-dataframe-using-its-partitions-in-java/

Comment: `df.foreachPartition(new AbstractFunction1<Iterator<Row>, BoxedUnit>(){
 @Override
 public BoxedUnit apply(Iterator<Row> v1) {
   Connection con = ConnectionFactory.createConnection();
   for (Row r : v1) {
     con.send(r);
   }
   con.close();
   return BoxedUnit.UNIT;
 }
 });`

You should consider a couple of things: 1. create connection method should be static to avoid unnecessary serialization. 2. The total number of created/closed connections will be equal to number of file partitions. But the number of *parallel* connections will be no more than number of executors.

Comment: Thank you so much Zyoma! I have one more question on this use case. Actually my data is ordered by timestamp. How can we ensure that the client receives the data in the same order? Attach an ID for each connection?

Comment: This approach doesn't provide such kind of guarantee. You have a couple of options though. 1. Receive all the data and sort it inside of application. 2. Dataset can be too big, in this case you can just save your DataFrame somewhere (like HDFS i.e.) in any format and notify your application that data is ready for reading.

Comment: Thank you for your help Zyoma!